# Haskell Aeson json encoding bytestrings

Tags: json, haskell, serialization, bytestring, aeson

I need to serialize a record in Haskell, and am trying to do it with [Aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:parseJSON).  The problem is that some of the fields are ByteStrings, and I can't work out from the examples how to encode them.  My idea is to first convert them to text via base64.  Here is what I have so far (I put 'undefined' where I didn't know what to do):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import qualified Data.Aeson as J
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Base64 as B64
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as E
import qualified GHC.Generics as G

data Data = Data
  { number :: Int
  , bytestring :: B.ByteString
  } deriving (G.Generic, Show)

instance J.ToJSON Data where
  toEncoding = J.genericToEncoding J.defaultOptions

instance J.FromJSON Data

instance J.FromJSON B.ByteString where
  parseJSON = undefined

instance J.ToJSON B.ByteString where
  toJSON = undefined

byteStringToText :: B.ByteString -> T.Text
byteStringToText = E.decodeUtf8 . B64.encode

textToByteString :: T.Text -> B.ByteString
textToByteString txt =
  case B64.decode . E.encodeUtf8 $ txt of
    Left err -> error err
    Right bs -> bs

encodeDecode :: Data -> Maybe Data
encodeDecode = J.decode . J.encode

main :: IO ()
main = print $ encodeDecode $ Data 1 "A bytestring"
```

It would be good if it was not necessary to manually define new instances of ToJSON and FromJSON for every record, because I have quite a few different records with bytestrings in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parseJson` needs to return a value of type `Parser B.ByteString`, so you just need to call `pure` on the return value of `B64.decode`.

```
import Control.Monad

-- Generalized to any MonadPlus instance, not just Either String
textToByteString :: MonadPlus m =>  T.Text -> m B.ByteString
textToByteString = case B64.decode (E.encodeUtf8 x) of
                     Left _ -> mzero
                     Right bs -> pure bs

instance J.FromJSON B.ByteString where
  parseJSON (J.String x) = textToByteString x
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Here, I've chosen to return `mzero` both if you try to decode anything other than a JSON string and if there is a problem with the base-64 decoding.

Likewise, `toJSON` needs just needs to encode the `Text` value you create from the base64-encoded ByteString.

```
instance J.ToJSON B.ByteString where
  toJSON = J.toJSON . byteStringToText
```

---

You might want to consider using a newtype wrapper instead of defining the `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` instances on `B.ByteString` directly.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Why is it better to use a newtype wrapper for ByteString?

Comment: Mosty for the same reason you don't define `Monoid` for `Int`, as there are *lots* of ways you can define a monoid over the integers (`+` with 0, `*` with 1`, etc). Likewise, this is *a* way you could encode a `ByteString` value, but it's not the *only* way, so you "localize" the instances to your data type.